# Matplotlib set bar starting point value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset which I am plotting with the help of python's matplotlib as follows :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

n_groups = 10
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(15,10)
index = np.arange(0, n_groups * 2, 2)
print index
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.4
error_config = {'ecolor': '0.3'}

rects1 = plt.bar(index, df.Quant[0:10], bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='b',
                 error_kw=error_config,
                 label='Quant')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, df.English[0:10], bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='r',
                 error_kw=error_config,
                 label='English')

rects3 = plt.bar(index + bar_width * 2, df.Logical[0:10], bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='g',
                 error_kw=error_config,
                 label='Logical')

plt.xlabel('Group')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by Designation')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, df.Designation[0:10], rotation='vertical')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which results into the following chart :

[image]

As you can see, the values are differing just above 400 points. How do i reduce the scope of the chart from 400 and to beyond?

Also, I was trying to do the same in `seaborn` but couldn't find any example to do so.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean by "reducing the scope of the chart".  Are you asking how to change the y-limits?  (If so, see `plt.ylim` or `ax.set(ylim=[ymin, ymax])`)  You might also consider `plt.margins(x=0.05)` to center the x-limits on your data's extent.

Comment: @JoeKington fantastic, yeah that was what I wanted `ax.set`. Please pardon me for my poor choice of words :P

Answer (score 4):

Using `ax.set(ylim=[400, 600])` will do the trick. Here, 400 is the minimum value for y-axis and 600 is the maximum value for y-axis. Change it as required.

I have reproduced a part of your graph with the y-axis curtailed.
[image]

Comment: thanks! yeah as @JoeKington mentioned it in the comments, setting ax.set worked :)

Comment: btw, can you provide me a good library to perform spatial plots? I have tried matplotlib basemap which isn;t that well looking, folium which just takes an iframe. I need something better which I can convert into an image

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never done spatial plots. However, you may check out this page which contains a list of plotting libraries for python [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting). However, Matplotlib is the first choice and probably the best that python has to offer. But there are many other options out there. Particularly, Plotly seems to be a strong contender. I would be glad to know if you find a better alternative because I had faced problem with Matplotlib before and had to switch to Java from Python in the past due to this.

Comment: @KoustuvSinha - Have a look at cartopy.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: I want to do the same but I also have some negative values. How can I do that?